# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in" when getting checked values by data attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox, checkboxlist

This is the view of checkbox group
[image]

And this is my html code for the above view(there is more check boxes, only 2 mention here):

```
    <div class="panel-body subject_names">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <label for="checkboxes-0" class="col-md-7">
      KE1-Financial Accounting &amp; Reporting Fundamen
      </label>
      <input type="checkbox" data-subject-name="KE1-Financial Accounting &amp; Reporting Fundamen" data-subject-ai="925" class="big-checkbox col-md-1 subject1" name="exam_subjects" id="checkboxes-0" value="1012"> 
      <div class="col-md-4 pull-left">
         <input id="training_institute" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="" class="input-md">
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-12">
      <label for="checkboxes-0" class="col-md-7">
      KE2-Management Accounting Information
      </label>
      <input type="checkbox" data-subject-name="KE2-Management Accounting Information" data-subject-ai="926" class="big-checkbox col-md-1 subject1" name="exam_subjects" id="checkboxes-0" value="1013"> 
      <div class="col-md-4 pull-left">
         <input id="training_institute" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="" class="input-md">
      </div>
   </div>


</div>
```

and this is my js code :

```
var subjects_names = [];
$.each($("input[name='exam_subjects']:checked").attr("data-subject-name"), function() {
    subjects_names.push($(this).val());
});
```

Exception:

```
Exam_application_c:775 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in KE1-Financial Accounting & Reporting Fundamen
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML code too, or better create a jsfiddle

Comment: @shiva HTML code included

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please don't rollback to various revisions of the post continuously. Stick to one revision. Continuous rollbacks makes it obvious that you're wanting to attract attention to your post by bumping it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) on a `string`, it needs to be an `object` or an `array`.

Try changing your code to this

```
var subjects_names = [];
$.each($("input[name='exam_subjects']:checked"), function () {
    subjects_names.push($(this).data("subjectName"));
});
```

Or better yet use [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) as your iterating over a jQuery object

```
var subjects_names = [];
$("input[name='exam_subjects']:checked").each(function () {
    subjects_names.push($(this).data("subjectName"));
});
```